# Display all related data when searchkeyword

Tags: php, mysql

This is part of my php file.

```
if(preg_match("/^[   a-zA-Z]+/", $_POST['searchName']))
{ 
    $name=$_POST['searchName']; 

    $con=mysql_connect ("localhost", "root",  "");

    $mydb=mysql_select_db("food",$con); 

    $result=mysql_query("SELECT Name, Price FROM info WHERE Name='$name'"); 

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    { 
        echo $row['Name'];
        echo $row['Price'];
    } 
} 
else
{ 
    echo  "<p>Please enter a search query</p>"; 
}
```

The problem for me now is for example I want to search for chicken pizza but it will only display the information when I type to full sentence which is chicken pizza. How can I make if I type chicken or other keyword and it will display to corresponding data related to chicken like chicken pie, chicken wings? Thanks for advicing.

*Note:I will change it to mysqli after I solved this problem*

Comment: use `Name LIKE '%$name%'` instead of `Name='$name'`,

Comment: You're probably after the `LIKE` syntax. See the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html).

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user parameters are **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) that can be exploited.

Comment: Changing to `mysqli` now would save you a lot of hassle here. Changing to PDO would be even better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the LIKE operator here. `LIKE` comes with varieties of ways. You can use `%` before the keyword, after the keyword, and both before and after the keyword.

Example:

```
"SELECT Name, Price FROM info WHERE Name LIKE '%$name%'"
```

> **Tip:** The "%" sign is used to define wildcards (missing letters) both
>   before and after the pattern.

And Stop using `mysql_*`, start with `mysqli_*` OR `PDO`.

Comment: Thanks it worked. How about if i wan show error when i type inrelevant data?

Comment: you can check `mysqli_num_rows` to check is there any return data or not, if not then make the error message..

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Name, Price FROM info WHERE Name LIKE 'chicken%'
```